# Edit multiline text in Xcode's property lists

Tags: xcode, ide, xcode4.6, property-list

I've some property lists in my Xcode project for different strings (and its localization).
The strings are longer and often multi line. But in Xcode it's hard to edit those strings in one single line only. How can I expand or resize the line's height for better string editing in the Xcode IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the plist editor in Xcode, that is not possible.

What you can do, however, is to right-click on the entry in the file browser and choose "Open as > Source Code". You then see the raw XML text of the plist which is much easier to edit.

Just make sure you don't mess up the tags - otherwise Xcode will complain that it's not a valid file.

Comment: This is not possible since I use HTML (with tags) in my text so I have to save the plist as binary.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, and no, you don't have to save XML with HTML as binary. HTML is essentially also just XML or text, so you can still edit it as described.

Comment: Also, HTML inside XML opens a whole other set of problems. This is not the question you asked about editing multiline plists.